# JS IOS issue: null is not an object

Tags: javascript, ios, null

I have two arrays:

```
var tableIdsSold = [3, 38, 43, 44];
    var tableIdsBook = [40];
```

I receive array elements from backend, right after "body" tag opens.
Then, before "body" tags closes, i put link to "main.js".
In "main.js" i have this code runnin:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tableIdsSold.length; i++) {
document.querySelector('[data-circleId="' + tableIdsSold[i] + '"]').classList.add('purchased');
```

}

and same for second array.
So i just run through array, use array element as id. When script finds element with right id - it should add class to html tag "circle".
So the problem is: script works everywhere, but not in IOS. If i open this page in mac (safari/chrome) or iphone 5/6 (safari/chrome), i get this error in console:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector('[data-circleId="' + tableIdsSold[i] + '"]').classList')

Script runs in "window.onload" function. What's causing the problem?
Sorry for bad english

Comment: It means that either `.querySelector()` is returning `null`, or that the browser does not support `.classList`. *edit* MDN says that iOS Safari supports `.classList` APIs so it's probably that the `.querySelector()` call is returning `null`. It should be very easy to determine that with some `console.log()` calls.

Comment: So the problem was: somehow ios html interpretator writes "data-circleId" class as "data-circleid". Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

> The [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) method [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first `Element` within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, `null` is returned.

You need to check if this `document.querySelector('[data-circleId="' + tableIdsSold[i] + '"]')` null then no need to do action.

---

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
for (var i = 0; i < tableIdsSold.length; i++) {
    let circleId = document.querySelector('[data-circleId="' + tableIdsSold[i] + '"]');
    if (circleId) {
        circleId.classList.add('purchased');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was: somehow ios html interpretator writes "data-circleId" class as "data-circleid". My JS script couldn't find "data-circleId" because of this.